# Vanishing of self-hom in Spanier–Whitehead stabilization category

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, limits-and-colimits, triangulated-categories, stable-category

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\SW{SW}$Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. For $R$-modules $M,N$, let $\mathcal I_R(M,N)$ be the collection of all $f\in \text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ that factors through some projective $R$-module. Put $\underline{\Hom}_R(M,N):=\Hom_R(M,N)/\mathcal I_R(M,N)$ and for every $m,n\in \mathbb Z$, put $\Hom_{\SW(R)}(M[n],N[m]) :=\varinjlim_{i\geq m,n} \underline{\Hom}_R (\Omega_R^{i-n} M , \Omega^{i-m}N)$.
It is clear to see that $\underline{\Hom}_R(M,M)=0$ if and only if $M$ is projective.

My question is: What can we say about $M$ if $\Hom_{\SW(R)}(M[n],M[n])=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$? I am willing to assume $M$ is finitely generated (but I think it won't make a difference for the answer).

Comment: TeX note: $\underrightarrow\lim$ `\underrightarrow\lim` is really semantically  $\varinjlim$ `\varinjlim`.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is statement 4.2 in Kropholler's paper, "[On groups of type $(FP)_\infty$](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90136-H)" (1993). This states that your colimit is zero if and only if the module $M$ has finite projective dimension over $R$. No finite generation hypotheses are involved. His (and my) notation for this is $\smash{\widehat{\operatorname{Ext}}}^0_R(M,M)$.

Comment: I used this a lot in my paper, "Complexity and varieties for infinite groups, I" (J Algebra 1997).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457095/vanishing-of-self-hom-in-spanier-whitehead-stabilization-category#comment1184014_457146), great!  I have [edited](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/457146/3) accordingly.